# confused as to whether to use a do-while or while loop for dice game

Tags: loops, while-loop, do-while

Wanted to know whether a for-loop is better or if I should stick with a while loop. And if so why or why not.

```
srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
bool result;
bool end = false;
int win, lose;
char answer;

win = lose = 0;
while (!end) {
    result = play_game();

    if (result) {
        printf("You win!\n\n");
        ++win;
    } else {
        printf("You Lose!\n\n");
        ++lose;
    }

    printf("Do you want to play again (y/n) ");
    if ((toupper(answer = getchar())) == 'Y') {
        end = false;
    } else if ((toupper(answer = getchar())) == 'N'){
        end = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Twelve or a dozen? Sometimes. Yes.

Comment: Is this question about a do-while versus while or a for-loop versus while-loop? The title doesn't match the post content.

Comment: Language tag would be nice. A lot of languages with C-like syntax out there. Could technically be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a do-while as long as you're not limited to a certain amount of plays.

```
char answer;
do
{
    answer = toupper(getchar());
    // ...
} while (answer == 'Y');
```

The difference here is that the do-block will be ran at **least** one time.
If the condition is met again (`answer == 'Y'`), then the do-block will be ran again, otherwise it'll break out.